# IPConfig lists very strange tunnel adapter

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I was trying to troubleshoot a different computer on my network, and ran `ipconfig` on MY computer for reference.  One of the adapters listed is -

```
Tunnel adapter satapi.GHGKZ.com:
```

Google has virtually nothing about ghgkz other than ghgkz.com's whois entry -

```
Domain Name: GHGKZ.COM
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
Registrant Name: External Admin
Registrant Organization: Greenleaf Hospitality Group
```

We do not use godaddy in any capacity and are certainly not associated with greenleaf.  Anyone have any thoughts on this?  Odd references to random domains kinda give me the chills...

Comment: It's a 6 to 4 tunnel adapter, possibly it was installed as a part of some other package..